# Is it possible to inclue a variable in a "default" string of a setting in Schema liquid in Shopify?

Tags: shopify, liquid

Is it possible to include a variable in a "default" string of a setting in Schema liquid in Shopify ?
Here is a snap of my code:
inside the {% schema %} section:

```
{
  "type": "textarea",
  "id": "free_shipping_announcement_message",
  "label": "Shipping",
  "default": "Spend {{ variable }} to get free shipping"
}
```

How can I add a liquid variable that is declared in the same document?

Thanks,

Comment: What is the Shopify default behavior when you tried the same?

Comment: You can't do the same  into Shopify, it is treated as string while saving it and show as it https://prnt.sc/1smyy2v

Comment: Exactly, when I put what you have in the screenshot, it treats it as a string and not as a variable.
I other themes, I saw this written :
`Spend ||amount|| to get free shipping`
I tried using the || but it doesn't work as well. (I don't have access to the code of these themes to see how exactly it is written).

Comment: Sometimes coder mentioned a format ||amount|| is parsed using code and shows the actual amount when parsing in liquid. they can't use it as a variable but like a unique selector into the string where the amount is inserted

Comment: Thanks for your answer !
If you have any example, it would be great, as I am not very confortable with selectors in liquid. Otherwise, I will continue searching.
Thanks :)

Comment: Here into once website, I have create the same where I will check for __timer__ and replace it with liquid while parsing it https://prnt.sc/1so7zye

Comment: Here is the liquid part where I am checking it and replacing it with div element and append the timer using JS lib on load.https://prnt.sc/1so8o2k

Comment: I hope it will gives you an idea about it